# Calculation of solute, pressure and water potential

Tags: homework, plant-physiology, osmosis

What would be the water potential (Ψw), solute potential (Ψs) and pressure potential (Ψp) at equilibrium when a cell with Ψs= – 0.7 MPa and Ψp= 0.7 MPa is placed in a solution with Ψs= – 0.5 MPa?  ([Source](https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/inbo2014-Q.pdf))

a. Ψw= – 0.2 MPa, Ψs= – 0.5 MPa, Ψp= – 0.5 MPa

b. Ψw= – 0.5 MPa, Ψs= – 0.7 MPa, Ψp= 0.2 MPa

c. Ψw= – 0.5 MPa, Ψs= – 0.5 MPa, Ψp= 0 MPa

d. Ψw= – 0.3 MPa, Ψs= – 0.3 MPa, Ψp= 0 MPa

Water potential in the cell (before being placed in the solution) will be zero. But after it is placed, due to exosmosis water should move out thereby decreasing its water potential. But by how much does the water potential decrease (when the cell is in equilibrium) and what effect that might have on the cell's solute and pressure potential is what I am unable to calculate.